# See package names gnome-software

Tags: package-management, software-installation, gnome-software

Is there a way to configure `gnome-software` such that I can see the package names?  In the old (and slow!) `software-center` it was default - which I appreciated, as I usually find the software via software centers and install via the terminal.  (Reason: long story, but there is a good reason.)  Is it possible to see the package titles in the `gnome-software` program?

Comment: It's impossible rignt now, but you can support this issue to get it implemented: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/issues/644

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no for now at least, gnome are obsessed with simplifying everything to the point it is almost useless (IMO).

There are some alternatives though if you like more information.

The old software center is still available

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

Also synaptic package manger offers a front end for apt with all the information you can eat

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

There are also websites to visit [Ubuntufree](http://www.ubuntufree.com/apps-for-ubuntu/) seems nice, I never used it though and the [apps directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) too but it seems to not be updated as of writing.